# React native - flex properties not centering form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a form wrapped inside a parent container (which is a **KeyboardAvoidingView**), and after adding the appropriate flex properties to center the form horizontally and vertically, the form does not center in either direction.

Here is the code for the parent container containing the form:

```
const AuthScreen = () => {
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false)

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <PageContainer>
                <ScrollView>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.keyboardAvoidingView} behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "height" : undefined} keyboardVerticalOffset={100}>
                        <LoginForm />
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </ScrollView>
            </PageContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    keyboardAvoidingView: {
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
    }
})

export default AuthScreen
```

Here is the form (LoginForm) code. This is the form I expect to be centered:

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const inputChangedHandler = useCallback((id, value) => {
    // Validate current input status
    const validationResult = validateInput(id, value)
    dispatchFormState({id, value, validationResult})
  }, [dispatchFormState])

  return (
    <>
       <Input errorText={formState.inputValidities["email"]} inputChanged={inputChangedHandler} id="email" placeholder="Email Address" /> 
       <Input errorText={formState.inputValidities["password"]}  inputChanged={inputChangedHandler} id="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
       <SubmitButton title='Login' />
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 
})

export default LoginForm
```

The code for the **Input **component:

```
const Input = props => {

    const {id, placeholder, inputChanged, errorText} = props

    return <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => inputChanged(id, text)} placeholderTextColor="white" style={styles.input} placeholder={placeholder} />
        </View>

        {
            errorText &&
            <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
                <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{errorText[0]}</Text>
            </View>
        
        }
    </View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 32,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: colors.inputBgColor,
        flex: 1,
        paddingVertical: 6,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        letterSpacing: 0.3,
        color: 'white'
    },  
    inputContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    errorContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 10
    }
})

export default Input
```

Could I get some ideas on why this form is not centering? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [contentContainerStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) to apply style to the scroll view content container. Using `flexGrow: 1` allows children to grow when needed.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue with your code might be related to the combination of using a `KeyboardAvoidingView` and the `flex` property on the parent container. When using `KeyboardAvoidingView` and trying to center its content using `flex`, you might encounter unexpected behavior.

Here's a suggestion to fix the issue:

1. Remove the `flex: 1` from the `keyboardAvoidingView` style in `AuthScreen`. This will prevent the `KeyboardAvoidingView` from taking all the available space.
2. Instead of using `alignItems: 'center'` and `justifyContent: 'center'` on the `keyboardAvoidingView`, apply these properties to the `ScrollView` and the `PageContainer` components. This will center the `KeyboardAvoidingView` within the `ScrollView` and the `PageContainer` within the `SafeAreaView`.

Here's the updated code for `AuthScreen`:

```js
const AuthScreen = () => {
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <PageContainer style={styles.pageContainer}>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView
                        style={styles.keyboardAvoidingView}
                        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "height" : undefined}
                        keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
                    >
                        <LoginForm />
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </ScrollView>
            </PageContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    scrollViewContent: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    keyboardAvoidingView: {
        padding: 10,
    },
});

export default AuthScreen;
```

Note that I added two new styles: `pageContainer` and `scrollViewContent`, which handle the centering of the content within the `SafeAreaView` and `ScrollView`, respectively.

With this change, your `LoginForm` component should now be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @GOVINDARAJ Unfortunately, this solution has not worked, and both the form inputs are stretched out vertically.